# Finding a scalar potential from

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

So I have a force given by:

$$ F = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^n(xi+yj+zk)$$

From this I want to find a scalar potential (defined as $\phi(x,y,z)$) so that $F = -\nabla\phi$. Can anyone give me some pointers or the starting point for doing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)}\left( x^2+y^2+z^2  \right)^{n+1 }   \right]=x\left(x^2+y^2+z^2 \right)^n
$$

Comment: I see it. Can we just use one component, so say, use the x component? Or should I show phi is what is in your square brackets for each component?

Comment: You must werify for all components ( easy in this case) and note that if  you want $ F=-\nabla \phi$  you have a change of sign.

Comment: Ok, and yes I have what you have in square brackets but negative...

Comment: Another quick follow up question, it is asking for what value of n does the scalar potential diverge at both the origin and infinity? What does this mean, and how would I work it out? And my gut reaction is that the value is n=-1...

Comment: Not so quick ! It's better that you ask another question :) Aniway, for n=0 the potential is a constant. And since the potential is allways defined less to a constant it can be $0$.